# BoxCox transformation error : "response variable must be positive"

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation

I estimate a model with linear regression:

```
model <- lm(orders ~ 
          day +
         holiday_dummies 
        ,data=training_df, na.action = na.exclude)

summary(model)
```

my response variable is zero somewhere but positive - in fact:

```
summary(df$orders)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   0.000   3.174   4.000  67.000
```

When I try to estimate the boxcox like:

```
bc<-boxcox(model,plotit = T)
```

I get:

```
 Error in boxcox.default(model, plotit = T): response variable must be positive
```

I shouldnt be a problem to have zero values right?

Hints are welcome!

Comment: Not really. The box-cox transformation includes the log transformation as a particular case. See, e.g., here https://www.r-bloggers.com/on-box-cox-transform-in-regression-models/.

Comment: that would mean that both lambdas are zero. is there a way to fix one of them and just keep (log + c) and estimate just one? @utobi

Comment: There is only one lambda in box-cox transformation. A quick fix would be to add a small positive value to all of your observations prior to the box-cox transformation. Otherwise a zero-inflated model might be more appropriate.

Comment: As @utobi suggests since more than half your observations are zero any transformation is going to have a spike at the value which is the transformed zero so choosing a model which explicitly allows for clumping at zero looks a much better bet.

Comment: which kind of model would you advice? @mdewey

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i08) from JSS will help.